# Extrema of a product $u(x) v(x)$

Tags: calculus, soft-question

If we want to find the extrema of a function on $\mathbb{R}$ which is a product of functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$, then: $$\frac{d}{dx} (u(x)v(x))=u\frac{dv}{dx}+v\frac{du}{dx}=0$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{v}{u}=-\frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{du}=-\frac{dv}{du}$$

This equation is short and sweet, but I can't explain it on any more intuitive grounds. Any suggestions?

Comment: Be careful here. How do you define $\frac{dv}{du}$? Derivatives don't play nicely with cancellation; they can't just be treated like fractions.

Comment: Yeah so I was leaving that deliberately loose. I know it's not definable all the time, but when it is definable, then the explanation should cover that case too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand how the product rule was derived?  If you go back and prove it for yourself, you can at least see where it came from.

Re finding extrema, you could spend time working out some extrema without calculus.  Make up some specific function products and see: what's going up and how far, what's going down, are they reinforcing each other or fighting each other?  It's illuminating and will help you understand more about extrema.

It will also help a lot when you get a problem where taking derivatives does not work (regretfully there are many of those -- it's not that the theory collapses, it's just that it's not computable).

Once you see how extrema are computed the hard way for several examples, maybe you can connect the dots to the way the derivatives fit in.